# Running into problem when using choose folder in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder

So I have a folder with many files whose count changes regularly and I need to count them using AppleScript. I had a script like this in place at first:

```
tell application "Finder" to return count of (every file of (choose folder))
```

Later, while researching, I found something like this:

```
tell application "Finder" to return count files of (choose folder)
```

However neither seems to work. I can't use `System Events` either since the choose folder just results in an endless run loop when used inside a System Events-tell block.

The error I get is:

```
"Finder got an error: Expected a reference." number -1727
```

Comment: **System Events** can also handle it (although you might want to limit the count to visible files) - just don’t use the `choose folder` dialog in the application tell statement (a good habit to get into).

Comment: @user3439894 Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get just the *count* of *files* within the selected *folder* and not *subfolders* or *files* within *subfolders*, then use:

```
tell application "Finder" to return count files of container (choose folder)
```

If you want the full *count* of *items* within a *folder*, then use:

```
tell application "Finder" to return count items of entire contents of container (choose folder)
```